# Why my c++ code runs on Linux but not on Windows, is there a problema with RAM memory?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, memory, memory-management

I'm new programming and I have found a problem 
I'm defining a c++ array like this

```
double name[512][512]
```

But when I run it on Windows(it compiles without errors) it crashes. When I run on Linux(Ubuntu) it runs how it should do it without problems. I think Windows is restricting the memory my program can take, am I right? How can I solve it? Thanks to everyone who can give me a hand.

Comment: are you sure it's about that ? some libraries work on linux and doesn't on windows be sure !

Comment: What are you using to build your program on each platform?

Comment: Different default stack sizes would be my guess.

Comment: `512 * 512 * 8 = 2097152` (over 2M of stack space required). Better `double (*name)[512];` and then `name = malloc (512 * sizeof *name);` which will dynamically allocate the same number of bytes and allow you the same access through the pointer to array of `512` chars.

Comment: We should have an award for questions from new folks where the answer is literally `Stack Overflow`. :)

Comment: For your next questions, please provide an [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you, you are right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm *guessing* (since you did not provide an MCVE) that your `name` array is an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), so it gets allocated on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

BTW the problem is *not* in the RAM (which is managed by the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system); [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) programs don't use *directly* RAM but [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)) but in the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (its stack segment) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). On Linux, you could use `/proc/` (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html)) to query your process' virtual address space. And read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to understand the role of the OS.

Notice that on x86-64 `sizeof(name)` is probably 2097152 bytes.

**The call stack is limited in size**. On Linux, the usual limit is 4 or 8 megabytes (but there is a way to change it), on Windows it is rumored to be 1 megabyte. You've got a [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

You are likely above that limit. Consider using some [dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#DYNAMIC) (e.g. with [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new); however by using higher level C++ constructs such as [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) you should generally avoid explicitly using it). Most C++ standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), notably [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (but not `std::array`) use it (the heap) for internal data.

As a rule of thumb, each call frame should be rather small (e.g. kilobytes).

And the compiler could have warned you, if you compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wstack-usage=1500 -g` on Linux. Learn also to [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Be [afraid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You could also use some extra [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) like [Boost](http://boost.org/) (or something else) providing matrixes, or have your own `Matrix` [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (which would heap-allocate its data). Be aware of the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Take several weeks to read some good [C++ programming book](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/), but be aware that C++ is a *very difficult and complex programming language* (so read also [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) to learn more general programming concepts and play with some [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) implementation such as [Racket](https://racket-lang.org/)). Later, you could read some [book](http://gchandbook.org/) on [Garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) (the concepts there are relevant to [memory management](http://ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management)).

Comment: What a good explanation, thank you. Can you give me some references(books, websites,courses) where I can learn about that basic topic in memory management?

Comment: I added more references. You first need to learn C++ programming

Answer (score 0):

You are probably trying to allocate the array on the stack, and the stack size is smaller on the Windows system. If that is the case, make the array global or `static` and the problem will go away.

Another option is to allocate the array dynamically. For example:

```
struct Array {
    double vals[512][512];
};

// in a function:
auto name_guard = std::make_unique<Array>();
auto &name = name_guard->vals;
```

Here `name_guard` ensures that the storage will be deleted when no longer needed (as determined by the life-time of `name_guard`), and `name` has the same meaning as `name` in the question. Note that `name` must not be allowed to outlive the guard object.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting stack overflow.

`sizeof(double)` is 8 on Windows.

Thus, `8*512*512` is `2MB`.  If I'm not mistaken, the default stack size for the Visual Studio compiler is 1MB. The [/STACK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack) compiler switch on the linker can be used to increase this size.

As others are likely to point out, for large arrays, use the heap (malloc/new, free/delete) instead of taking up large amounts of stack with array variables.

Comment: Thanks dude, you are right, did know that